# How to implement an interface on a protected java class

Tags: java, class, interface, visibility, protected

I was looking to implement an interface on a package-private java class, but I am having some difficulty achieving this. Below is an example.

```
class Foo
{
    String something(String str)
    {
        return ""str+"!";
    }
}




public interface Bar
{
    String something(String str);
}
```

What is the best approach here? My end goal is to implement the Bar interface on the Foo class. I am hoping to be able to cast Foo as Bar: (Bar)Foo

The Bar interface and the Foo class are in separate packages. Is there a way to do this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The point of having the package level access it to precisely avoid seeing that class outside. What you can do however ( granted Foo is not final ) something like this:

```
C:\>type *.java
//Foo.java
package foo;
class Foo {
  String something( String s ) {
    return s + "!";
  }
}  
//Bar.java
package bar;
public interface Bar {
  public String something( String s );
}    
//Baz.java
package foo;    
import bar.Bar;    
public class Baz extends Foo implements Bar {
  // make sure you're overriding
  @Override
  public String something ( String s ) {
    return super.something( s );
  }
}     
//Use it: Main.java
package bar;
import foo.Baz;   
class Main {
  public static void main( String ... args ) {
    Bar bar = new Baz();
    System.out.println( bar.something("like this?"));
  }
}

C:\>java bar.Main
like this?!
```

Da da!

The trick is to define the child in the same package as the parent so you can create a public version of it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the approach I went for originally, but I am receiving the error: "something(string) in Foo cannot implement something(string) in Bar, attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public

Comment: I got it too. And then just added: `public String something( String s ) { return super.something( s ); }` You can copy the code I provided and see it for your self.

Comment: That's why it's necessary to override `something(s)` with the public version that returns `super.something(s)`.

Comment: Probably you misspell the overridden method add the `Override` annotation. See the update

Answer (score 2):

When you doesn't have control on a class but you want to make it look like an API that you have, then you [**Adapt**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) it to fit your needs. Hint: Adapter Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Foo needs to **implement** Bar

`protected class Foo implements Bar`

Also, I think `Foo.something` needs to be **public** in order to implement `Bar.something`

Side Note: While it was probably just as an example,

`return ""str+"!";`

should be:

`return str + "!";`

If Foo is package private, and you don't have access to the source, just the classfiles and/or the jar containing Foo.class, there's not much to do -- something that is package private is invisible to classes in the default package (where there is no package specified) and other packages.

Comment: Foo.something is not public, and I do not have access

Comment: Do you know if Foo.something is at least protected? According to your example, Foo.something is package-visible, and I don't know how much we can do about.

Comment: @andersra: What do you mean with "I do not have access"?

Comment: Foo is package-private and the interface is in another package. I edited the original question to reflect this, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use inheritance or composition if you don't have access to the source code of `Foo`.

```
// By logically including your code in the package containing Foo,
// you can now access it. If Foo belongs to the default package, sorry.
// This also doesn't work if the package is sealed.
package where.foo.resides;

public interface Bar {
    String something(String s);
}

// Inheritance
public class FooBar extends Foo implements Bar {
    public String something(String s) {
        return super.something(s);
    }
}

// Composition
public class ComposedFooBar implements Bar {
    private final Foo delegate;
    public ComposedFooBar(Foo delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public String something(String s) {
        return delegate.something(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake, does this solution still apply if Foo is package-private?

Comment: It depends. If `Foo` is in a sealed JAR file and you don't have the source code, you're out of luck (without reflection) since you can't refer to the `Foo` type outside of its package. That's probably not the case, so you can still create a file that starts with `package foo;` or whatever package contains `Foo` and use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bytecode injection with BCEL or ASM and setting the interface at runtime. It's tricky, though.

There might also be a way to change interaces with reflection, but I doubt it.

Private is there for a reason.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The bytecode injection approach is likely to result in a `VerifyError` or `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.  Also, you cannot change an interface by reflection ... but you can reflectively call a private method.